# Mysqli auto_increment support

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

On my website when a new user registers a ID is assigned to them and this ID is the primary key in my PHPMYADMIN database.

It auto_increments by one for each new user added.

Now what I want to know is how can I reset it too one without having to kill the table and bring it back.

Thanks for your support.

EDIT:

at the moment im developing a script so im testing my registration page out.

Comment: Hi there. Question: why would you want to reset the autoincrement?

Comment: *"PHPMYADMIN database"* no such thing, phpmyadmin is a script to mange databases, like any other php script

Comment: You should never trust the autoincrement values to either start from 1 or be incremented by 1. All that is guaranteed is that a value requested later will be greater than the one before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really must:

```
ALTER TABLE `TABLE_NAME` AUTO_INCREMENT =VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

in phpmyadmin you have table option 'operate' or 'operations'.
That's where you can reset the auto_increment value to 0